# How can I make sure only *.exe or *.dll file goes to output folder and any other build files goes to intermediate folder VS2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I created a C# project on VS2012 and I want that the output folder will only contain the *.exe/*.dll file and any other files that are created when building the project will go to the intermediate folder.

I have a property sheet that defines the intermediate location.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <BUILD_ROOT>f:\test</BUILD_ROOT>
    <BUILD_INTERMEDIATE>f:\test</BUILD_INTERMEDIATE>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BUILD_INTERMEDIATE)\inter\debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath >$(IntermediateOutputPath)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath >
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BUILD_INTERMEDIATE)\inter\Release\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath >$(IntermediateOutputPath)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath >
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I imported this property sheet to my project file manuallly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\PropertySheet.props" />
```

When I build the project, it creates separate folders for output and intermediate. Intermediate folder contains all the intermediate files along with pdb file. But it also contains the exe file.

But the problem I am facing is, the output folder also contains most of the file which are in intermediate folder too. Such as the pdb, exe, config etc.

Can anyone please help me by explaining what I should do so that only the .exe file will be in output folder and any other build time files will only stay in intermediate folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead create an additional "dist" folder (or similar) and copy the exe and dll files to that folder after the build. There are many MSBuild properties and targets that can place files in the output folder, and attempting to change this behavior could break functionality.

Also, if you specify `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` then you should not specify `IntermediateOutputPath`. In the case of the properties above, you appear to be trying to use this:

```
<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(BUILD_INTERMEDIATE)\inter\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
```

Comment: Thank for this idea.Actually I am converting a big project from VS2005 to VS 2012. While on VS2005, I did set separate intermediate and output folder and only the exe and dll used to go to the output folder.Your advice will solve my problem but I still have the question that what is the change in VS2012 that is causing all the build files going to both intermediate and output folder??

Comment: @Shahed There is no simple answer here. Files that are marked as "Copy to Output Folder" will appear in your output directory, as well as a number of files that are often considered part of the final build output (e.g. pdb and config files).

Answer (score 1):

If I was doing this I would create a bat file to run as a post build script that moved any non dll and exe files.

Comment: Agreed. Here's what I usually do to execute a post-build bat (`;` indicates new line since I can't format that in a comment but is not actually in command line script): if $(ConfigurationName) == Release exit 0;
cd $(ProjectDir);
"$(ProjectDir)"postBuild.bat;

Comment: Thank for this idea.Actually I am converting a big project from VS2005 to VS 2012. While on VS2005, I did set separate intermediate and output folder and only the exe and dll used to go to the output folder.Your advice will solve my problem but I still have the question that what is the change in VS2012 that is causing all the build files going to both intermediate and output folder??

Comment: @Shahed, Understood. I hate to provide an answer that doesn't answer your problem but suggests another method. I hate when others do it and I did it myself >_< Hope you are able to figure it out